# Definir o valor da variável como a opção escolhida no combobox (C#), C sharp

Tags: c#, c, winforms, windows

Olá. Eu estou criando um programa em C sharp (C#), através do Windows forms. E preciso que o valor de uma variável seja igual ao valor escolhido em uma combobox, por exemplo:

[image: Assim sendo, se eu selecionar 10 na combobox, quero que minha variável tenha o valor de 10. Como faço isso? Muito obrigado pela ajuda!]

Assim sendo, se eu selecionar 10 na combobox, quero que minha variável tenha o valor de 10. Como faço isso? Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

É só usar a propriedade `SelectedValue` do combo.

```cs
var valorComboBox = comboBox.SelectedValue;
```